# (Python, Flask) Flask route function takes too long due to IO bound, so client times out

Tags: python, github, flask, concurrency, github-webhook

I am currently developing a music streaming service from the ground up. I'm doing both, back and front end. I have a server that I'm using for testing during this development phase. It has a Go server application and also a clone of a GitHub repo where I push my Vue.js code for the front end.

The deployment process is simple. Once I push changes to the master branch, I'd `ssh` into the server, `cd` into the Vue.js project folder, `git pull`, `npm run build` and voila! Since it is such an easy and predictable task, I wanted to automate it using GitHub's webhooks and Python's Flask framework. So I've written this (and it kinda works):

```py
# this snippet only shows the important bits

def onpush(event: str, info: Dict):
    subprocess.run(SCRIPT, stdout=LOG_FILE)

@app.route('/github', methods=['POST'])
def github() -> str:
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/json':
        return '415 - unsupported media type'

    event: str = request.headers['X-GitHub-Event']
    info: Dict = request.json
    onpush(event, info) # takes too long! client times out since ...
    return '200 - OK'   # this return value is used as the response ...
                        # which means it's not sent until `onpush` is done
```

However, the `onpush` function runs `git pull` within its `subprocess.run` call (which takes time to fetch data from GitHub servers), and none of it is concurrent. So, using route's `return '200 - OK'` value as the server's response (which is what Flask does if I'm not mistaken) leads to the fact that:

1. GitHub webhoook client times out and displays payload as undelivered (even though on the server-side everything worked fine - it's just that client couldn't wait long enough to get the response they are expecting).
2. I cannot respond first and then call `onpush` since **responding = returning from function**.

[image: Webhooks call timed out]

So I am pretty much looking for a way to get this thing to respond quickly enough so that GitHub will not time out while still being able to `git pull`. This could probably be resolved with a bit of concurrency or threading but I really don't know how.

Comment: you should make it asynchronous. I would recommend creating a tracking ID once you get the API call and then trigger a new process in non blocking mode and capture logs against the tracking ID so that you can refer back to logs with a mapping in hand in case of any failure.

Comment: Hey, @akazuko could you show me how to do that? This is the [link to repo](https://github.com/sharpvik/morty-cd) for more context.